# US citizen, spouse of UK Citizen. Can I work two jobs, one in the US and one in the UK? Forecasting potential problems

Tags: united-kingdom, taxes, us-citizens, uk-visa, working

Getting all my ducks in a row for moving to the UK next spring.

- I will be entering the UK on a spousal visa, which grants me the right to work in the UK.
- I am currently employed for a multi-national employer, who will be transferring me to their UK entity. No issues there.
- **I have been offered a remote second job for an employer based in the US.**

Now, here's where it gets hairy.

- I expect to be over the FEIE limit.
- Will I run into problems having two jobs, one being paid into a UK bank account and one into US?
- Will my secondary employer get into trouble for employing a UK resident/US citizen if they have no established entity in the UK?
- Will my secondary employer still be able to make 401k contributions even if I'm not on US soil?
- Am I allowed to make both US and UK retirement contributions?
- Would it make a difference if the secondary job employs me as a 1099 contractor vs. a W2 employee?

I, of course, plan on reporting all of my income and paying the requisite taxes to HMRC.

Comment: Have you reviewed [IRS Publication 54](https://www.irs.gov/forms-pubs/about-publication-54) ?

Comment: It would almost certainly be easier as a 1099 contractor.  The laws governing W-2 employees basically assume the employee is in the US (and in a particular state in the US).  But don't forget that as a US citizen you'll have to declare all your income to the IRS, too, regardless of whether you take the second job.